# How to replace a html div id with php function without reloading the page

Tags: php, html

so after all the confusion here (my apologize)

here is what I have figure I will just re-write it here and make it clear and just for the future notes (I know people won't really need this) but then will just be like a case study

what I was actually wanted is like this example

```
***********************************************
** link1 - link2 - link3 - link4 - link5 **
***********************************************
** content here, here's the words **
** content here, here's the words **
** content here, here's the words **
** content here, here's the words **
** content here, here's the words **
***********************************************
```

then I found it something like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="page.php?link=1">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="page.php?link=2">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="page.php?link=3">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="page.php?link=4">Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="page.php?link=5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
<?php
if(!isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['link'])){ 
    $link = 1; 
} else { 
    $link = $HTTP_GET_VARS['link']; 
}

if ($link == 1) {
echo "<div id="player1"blah blah with video link1";
} elseif ($link == 2) {
echo "<div id="player2"blah blah with video link2"";
} elseif ($link == 3) {
echo "<p>Some text about link 3</p>";
} elseif ($link == 4) {
echo "<p>Some text about link 4</p>";
} else {
echo "<p>Some text about link 1</p>";
} 
?>
```

then @royrui clarify me that

the solution should be like this

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['link'])){ 
    $ch = 1; 
} else { 
    $ch = $_GET['link']; 
}

if ($link == 1) {
echo "<div id='player1'blah blah with video link1'";
} elseif ($link == 2) {
echo "<div id='player2'blah blah with video link2'";
} elseif ($link == 3) {
echo "<p>Some text about link 3</p>";
} elseif ($link == 4) {
echo "<p>Some text about link 4</p>";
} else {
echo "<p>Some text about link 1</p>";
} 
?>
```

so if you notice first thing I changed from if`(!isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['link'])){` 
 to `if(!isset($_GET['link'])){` 
  in the div all it was " so I change it to ' and now the div can be place in echo

and now every single time when people click on link 1 then that div will be place and 2 and so on.

I know it was my problem with the confusion questions but then I really appreciated with all the help from here.

I want to vote the best answers but all it was useful so I just thought of put together to answer myself in this first post

Thanks once again!

Comment: Could you possible format your code *as* code? I can't decipher what that's meant to be? To show code as code indent each line of code by four spaces, or select all your code and hit `ctrl`+`K`, or use the `{` button. Inline-code can be wrapped in backticks `\``.

Comment: I didn't see a question or a problem in your post.  I see what you want to do but what part of it isn't working?  What do you need help with?

Comment: First of all you code makes absolutely no sense. Also can you please give an example of what your code should look like before and after clicking a specific link.

Comment: First of all I'm so sorry that I didn't make it as a code before posting

Secondly

What I'm trying to do is something like the example again on the top I just post again

Comment: Sounds like you want Ajax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29 . And note that `$HTTP_GET_VARS` is deprecated, use `$_GET`.

Comment: So you mean istead of using 

$HTTP_GET_VARS['link'] then just use $_GET['link'] ??

Comment: I think you need to clarify what "without reloading page" means in the context of your question. It looks like you have everyone confused.

Comment: yeah I'm sorry about that I guess I was actually confused myself that the meaning of reloading the page is just like refresh but not to load a new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li><a href="page.php?link=1">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="page.php?link=5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['link'])){ 
    $link = 1; 
} else { 
    $link = $_GET['link']; 
}

if ($link == 1) {
echo "<div id='player1'>content here, here's the words plus html'video link1'</div>";
} elseif ($link == 2) {
echo "<div id='player1'>content here, here's the words plus html'video link1'</div>";
} elseif ($link == 3) {
  ...
} else {
echo "<p>Some text about link 1</p>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Well let say I have a page called tv.php and they have like 10 channels

I don't want to make 10 files for it instead I just want it to have like tv.php?ch=1 and tv.php?ch=2 and so on this is what I want

Comment: Hi instead of $HTTP_GET_VARS['link'], try change it to $_GET['link'] because $HTTP_GET_VARS['link'] is deprecated

Comment: Ok I will try that

but there is another problem

the script does not let me put the div in the echo line it will always give me parse error

Comment: Is it you just copy paste <div id="player1">content here, here's the words plus html"video link1"</div> into the echo? If u do so change the "player1" to 'player1' and "video link1" to 'video link1'

Comment: Welcome... I edited the post. If it is similar with what you want, can you just "accept" the answer so that people can know that this post has been solved? :)

Comment: Hi royrui I don't know if you still around but I just have a question

right now when I use this script the problem I have is that the device iPhone will not be remember for login, but the other device such as iPad and the rest all are fine including PC

I don't know what did I do wrong but I don't know what happen

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this with a javascript library called jquery, because the way you specify it, it looks like you want some AJAX functionality. You can do this in javascript without the use of a library, but then you have to work around quite some browser incompatibilities.

For this example, I will assume that all your navigation items are placed in an element with an id of nav.

then your javascript code should look like this:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
   $('#destinationdiv').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

The php looks like this: First, you make your main php file, such as page.php or whatever.

```
<?php
$secure=true; //This will ensure that users can't request any content without this script in between.
$pagenum = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
require('page'.$pagenum.'.php');
?>
```

and now, you add php files for every page of content that you want to serve, they should all look like this:

```
<?php if(!$secure) die("access denied!"); ?>
<h1>My awesome page content!</h1>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
```

so, to glue it all together
On your server, you should have files for each page you want the user to ba able to view. In your navigation, your a tags should have a href tag of page.php?page=1 or whatever. So, if you have a file called page1.php, and then put page.php?page=1, the javascript will stop the link from actually linking to that file. Instead, it will make a request to your server for page.php with a get variable called page, with a value of 1. the php script now looks on the server for a php file called page1.php and includes that in the current script. When PHP is done executing, the output will be sent back to the browser. Than the javascript load function that we called to request the page will insert it into the div we selected.

Comment: I will now edit my post to include the PHP. You can make it a lot simpler than the PHP in your question.

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: so in this case it will be page1.php or page.php?page=1

Comment: I wrote a response to you, but it's too long for a coment, will add it to my answer now.

Comment: Oh I see what the script would work but just to clarify myself that I understood this,

so basically I must have file name page.php and inside with content and div id and so on. and when people click on link 2 it will be like page.php?link=2 and it will replace some div instead?

or did I misunderstood some part?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that your PHP code is running on the server and not the browser. You need a combination of code running on both sides to accomplish this (known as AJAX).

Here is some example JavaScript code (no library needed) to replace the contents of a div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var http = false;

if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
  http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
  http = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 

function getLinkText(linkNo) {
  http.open("GET", "getLinkText.PHP?link=" + linkNo, true);
  http.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById('divLinkText').innerHTML = http.responseText;
    }
  }
  http.send(null);
}
</script>

<p><a href="javascript:getLinkText(1)">Link1</a></p>

<div id="divLinkText">
  This will be replaced by the AJAX Call.
</div>
```

The next step is to make a PHP page that returns the contents of the DIV tag at **getLinkText.PHP?link=1**. I'll leave that to you as it seems you have that part down.

As others have mentioned, adding the jQuery library makes this code a lot more compact and I recommend it.

Comment: well I don't know if its actually the same what actually I'm trying to explain

is like  I have a page called tv.php and they have like 10 channels I don't want to make 10 files for it instead I just want it to have like tv.php?ch=1 and tv.php?ch=2 and so on this is what I want

Comment: So when you click on a link for a channel it loads the info for that channel without reloading the whole page? This will do that. If you don't mind the whole page reloading, just put a conditional or switch statement in your php file and add a url parameter to decide which info to display.

Comment: I don't mind it will reload the page for a second or two, as long I don't have to get 10 files for my tv channel page then I will go with that script

but I just don't know which script to use

to be honest my programming course is starting in september but I just want to try something and I also have a website that people want me to do

so is kinda hard task for me because I use to only do HTML stuff but not php as yet